# Java Rest Delete error

Tags: java, mongodb, rest, jersey

I am using MongoDb and Morphia. I want to create DELETE method. This is my code:

```
@Path("deleted/{drinker}")
@DELETE
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void deleteOrder(@PathParam("drinker") String drinker) {
    datastore.delete(datastore.createQuery(Order.class).filter("drinker", drinker));
}
```

And then I have Method Not Allowed Error. What is the reason?

Answer (score 1):

`HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed` returned by Jersey means you use wrong HTTP method to issue the request.

Please make sure you issue the request with the correct HTTP method which is `DELETE` in your case.